# MVC app hosted on azure. Printing error

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, rdlc, reportviewer

I create MVC app hosted on azure, the app contains report viewer control that runs an rdlc report. Printing does not work, any thoughts?

Comment: does it work when hosted on another IIS locally? Any errors you get in browser console?

Comment: Yes, it works locally after downloading the active x control.

Comment: the error i get when printing from Azure is a generic one "An error occurred during printing." (0x80004005)"